# \pause does not work in a customized document class (using beamer)

Tags: beamer, overlays, documentclass-writing

I've written my own class file from beamer to avoid repeating all the preamble I'm used to use. Nothing complicated.

I'm facing a (simple) issue : the `\pause` command does not work.

Here is a MWE

```
    \documentclass{perso}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
    blablabla
    \pause
    blablabla
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

with the MWE of the perso class

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]%
    \ProvidesClass{perso}[2018/06/19 Mise en forme des diapositives 2018]
    \LoadClass{beamer}
    \RequirePackage{multirow}
```

Comment: As things are, your example throws critical errors. It does seem though you forgot to rename the class internally. Try `\ProvidesClass{perso}` instead. It does work here with it.

Comment: of course, essai_classe is the real name I use. but it still does not work. I modified the typp

Comment: I have no problem here. `\pause` does what it should do: waiting for `Enter`. Up-to-date TL2018. What viewer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

OK I misidentified the problem. My MWE works indeed. 
My problem was when I use `\pause` and a `textblock` environment...

I solved my problem including the `textblock` inside an `\only<2->` macro.